# Is it a good idea to use up-votes to down-votes ratio to judge a potential moderator's character?

Tags: discussion, voting, moderator-election

In my opinion, it can show a person's attitude towards the community. Thoughts?

Comment: If it's about up-votes to down-votes ratio on meta... maybe, I don't know.

Comment: @user202729 I don't see how Meta is any different in this regard.

Comment: @RobertColumbia "it can show that the community agree with them"?

Comment: @user202729 I think the question is about the number of upvotes and downvotes they've **cast**... which doesn't really tell you much other than whether they use downvotes a lot.

Comment: @user202729 character and agreement are two separate concepts. It's like claiming that because someone has the same taste in automobiles as you, they are therefore a better person.

Comment: So... look like I've misunderstood the question, as Catija pointed out.

Comment: @Catija yes, I interpreted it that way too, otherwise the question is more or less equivalent to judging based on rep.

Comment: @Catija Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, why are people downvoting? Is there anything wrong with the question or is it cause you don't share the same opinion?

Comment: @Tachyon, What would you consider to be the *optimum* ratio of upvotes to downvotes?

Comment: The votes here show the voters attitude towards the community. And I think they are right.

Comment: ["To someone unfamiliar with the site and how things operate here, at first glance a high number of downvotes would seem to indicate harsh treatment of others. That's not at all the case."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/220580/135615)

Comment: @StephenRauch Well, I was thinking ratio close to 1:1 would be optimum because low-quality questions get answered as well and often with more than one valid answer. I agree with people that downvoting bad questions/answers is important but IMO, so is upvoting good questions/answers.

Comment: @BradLarson I like your answer and I agree with your reasoning but your activity history is telling a different story :)

Comment: This only makes sense if users are encountering an equal number of good and bad posts every day and that just isn't true, especially if you spend a lot of time in review queues (and probably certain tags).

Comment: @BSMP Please excuse my ignorance I don't know much about how review queues work but do people have to downvote every question in the review queue? Also, questions under review still get valid/helpful answer(s), right? What I'm trying to say is that you always have a choice.

Comment: *do people have to downvote every question in the review queue* No, and they most likely don't. But 1) you're still encountering questions AND answers that are **more likely to have problems** because you're looking at posts that got flagged and 2) not all questions under review get valid/helpful answers. Sometimes they have zero answers. Sometimes the answers are wrong. Sometimes the thing you're reviewing IS an answer post (because what got posted wasn't an attempt to answer at all).

Comment: If 85% of the posts someone sees fits the criteria for being down voted it doesn't make sense for their voting record to be 50/50. That would mean they're either not voting or even up voting things that should be down voted.

Comment: There's plenty of good content to upvote if you **do** want to upvote.

Answer (score 22):

Someone that routinely downvotes poorly researched, incomplete, or off-topic questions is actually among one of the best people here.  They're helping us weed out the garbage and push the poor content to the bottom of the heap to make room for the good content.

Someone that routinely *upvotes* poorly researched, incomplete or off-topic questions is actively harming the site by making it harder to find good and high quality questions and answers.

I didn't realize that "mean" was at play when doing janitor work here.

<sup>If they're rude in comments, that's a different matter.  Flag that.</sup>

Comment: Fair enough but upvoting on-topic questions is as important as downvoting off-topic questions.

Comment: @Tachyon: Sure.  But at no point does that quantify "meanness".

Comment: So you're saying it _is_ a good idea: the lower the up/down ratio, the better the candidate. ;)

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Well, no.  I'm saying that they're *probably* doing a lot of curating of bad content.  Trying to extrapolate whether or not they'd make a good moderator from votes *alone* is silly... ;)

Comment: This is one of those metrics that in theory *could* mean something, but in reality is so unreliable and drowned in noise that it's not really any better than judging by height or by 3rd grade math scores.

Comment: A very deft parry.

Answer (score 17):

No.

Votes on Stack Overflow are about content, not posters. Voting here has nothing to do with "character". Upvoting is not "virtuous" any more than downvoting is antisocial.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your opinion but if a person downvotes a lot, wouldn't that mean that they are mean-spirited? I'm trying to keep an open mind; however, I'm not convinced by your answer.

Comment: @Tachyon here is the famous example of user you call "mean-spirited" - https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert?tab=topactivity...

Comment: @Tachyon "a lot" is really subjective, do you consider it a lot if a person gives 5 downvotes in one day? 15? If they have a 2/5 downvote to upvote ratio? 4/5? And even so... why would this ever be considered mean-spirited? Since when is an evaluation of the utility of a post mean? Sure, a person could be mean and even rude if they write a comment to the user, but the downvotes are not mean. See the other answer as to why downvotes can be and are good.